# Linux - Avoid memcpy before sending to NIC to create packet?

Tags: linux, sockets, nic

### Context

Debian 64 bits.
Raw sockets.
Trying to find the most efficient way to send data to the NIC.
User space networking. Avoid the kernel as much as possible.

### Question

Does a NIC need a buffer ready to send or is it possible for it to pass multiple pointers to where the information is and let the NIC seek it just before sending it? I am referring to the `send/sendto` calls.
It would avoid multiple `memcpy`.

Is it possible or not? ( I will use netmap or dpdk right after but it is important for me to know if I can avoid multiple `memcpy` upfront to set the data to send.)

**Edit**: I am quite sure what I want to do is not possible since the NIC won't access the OS mapping. So there is no way to avoid multiple `memcpy` I guess..

**Edit2**: what i am seeking for is called scatter gather. My main concern is the kernel bypass constraint now.

Comment: If it's a file you could use sendfile, or abuse splice.

Comment: Sendfile is slow and splice cause pipes overheads. i update with the kernel bypass requirement.

Comment: writev then instead, just reusing whatever buffers your data is already in?

Comment: Yes some parts ! writev will loop and memcpy at each pointers. It just hides what i already do/can do. having the nic sending the different parts directly after reading the location would be nice (much less memory pressure <-> just holding an array of pointers)

Comment: i am quite sure what i want is not possible since the NIC won't access the OS mapping.

Comment: [writev](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/11664383/) does not copy  buffers. Writing scattered buffers is why writev exists.

Comment: There is Netmap framework: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/netmap/ I read a paper about it couple of years ago: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2103536 Just FYI.

Comment: Yes Sergey, as mentioned those are the next step for my application. But at first I love to understand all the intrinsics :) Thanks

Comment: @msw: writev is my man. would not writev create an expensive context-switch to operate (I am in a userpace network stack context) ? every nanosecond counts.